# Why isn't the question-mark working in this glob?

Tags: bash, wildcards

What am I doing wrong in the glob below? It looks like it should work according to my reading of [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

> A '?' (not between brackets) matches any single character.

```
$ touch file.txt file.text
$ ls file.*
file.text  file.txt
$ ls file.te?xt
ls: cannot access 'file.te?xt': No such file or directory

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `?` matches a single character (like `.` in a regular expression).  You have no file matching the pattern `file.te?xt` so the pattern remains unexpanded.

You may have expected it to work as in a regular expression, where it means "zero or one of the previous expression". Unfortunately, there is no such wildcard in `bash`.

... unless you enable the `extglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then the pattern `?(list)` would match zero or one of the patterns in `list`.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls file.t?(e)xt
file.text file.txt
```